# How to set any attribute of Select lke disabled='disabled' by using ViewHelper in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using Zend Frameworks ViewHelpers.
I am trying to pass something to set disabled attribute in SELECT. For example if

```
$countries = array(1=>'Select Option', 2=>'us', 3=>'uk')
```

and 
`formSelect('country','us',null,$this->countries)`

I need to diable first option i.e. 'Select Option'

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks in addvance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can disable one element? If you disable it then why have it at all?

You can only disable the whole `<select>` input.

Suggest you write validation to not accept the first element.

Edit after OP's comment about being able to do this

Here is another answer

```
// Get the countries element (do this after adding your options), then set the 
// attribute disable for option '1'
$form->getElement("countries")->setAttrib("disable", array(1));
```

This is suggested [here](http://snipplr.com/view/37588/zend-framework--form-element-select-options-disable/)

Comment: actually i need to display it(just to ask user that Select Following option) but it not be selectable

Comment: You need validation then, at least at the server side. I am pretty sure you cannot disable individual `<option>` elements within a `<select>` element. Try it using basic HTML then you'll know.

Comment: Try this 
<select>
 <option disabled = "disabled">--SELECT OPTION--</option>
 <option  selected = "selected" value = "us">US</option>
 <option value = "uk">UK</option>
</select>

Comment: i hope you can see, you can do it in normal HTML

Comment: Perfect! That link had exactly the droids I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

There IS a way of doing it through Zend_Form (at least on my current ve 1.11):

```
$this->addElement
(
    "select","selectName", 
    array("multiOptions"=>array("one","two","three"), "disable"=>array(0,1))
);
```

That one will disable first two options.

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to jakenoble.
Just reformatted the code to use the formSelect-viewhelper instead of a form-element.

```
<?php
$countries = array(1 => 'Select Option', 2 => 'us', 3 =>'uk');
echo $this->formSelect('country', 2, array('disable' => array(1)), $countries)
```

This will result in:

```
<select name="country" id="country"> 
    <option value="1" label="Select Option" disabled="disabled">Select Option</option> 
    <option value="2" label="us" selected="selected">us</option> 
    <option value="3" label="uk">uk</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: Hmm, this does work for me. I'm using the latest Zend 1.* version. Seems I'm following the code as you've written it: `$this->formSelect(
            $nationality->getName(),
            $nationality->getValue(),
            array( 'disable' => array(1)),
            $nationality->getMultiOptions()
        );`. This is right huh? Or is this ZF2?